# JavaFX WebView: how to check if form is valid?

Tags: java, html, validation, javafx, webview

Is there a way to tell if a form is valid from Java?

Basically, a method that returns true if all input fields constrains are satisfied and false otherwise.

Strangely enough, `org.w3c.dom.html.HTMLFormElement` doesn't actually have a `checkValidity()` method.

EDIT:

Even more strangely, the implementation `com.sun.webkit.dom.HTMLFormElementImpl` does support the method `checkValidity()`. Unfortunately, the package `com.sun.webkit` is not accessible directly and thus the method is unavailable.

Comment: As far as I know, HTML does not do validation.  Validation is done by JavaScript and/or done on the server of the form’s action URL.

Comment: @VGR you can google "html5 form validation" to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM objects like HTMLFormElement only model structure.  They are not capable of executing JavaScript.

However, WebEngine itself does have a JavaScript interpreter, which you can invoke using the [executeScript](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
boolean valid = (Boolean) webView.getEngine().executeScript(
    "document.forms[0].checkValidity();");
```

The `checkValidity()` method is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation#Methods) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlformelement-checkvalidity).

Comment: How do you know the first form (`forms[0]`) is the one submitted?

Comment: I don’t.  That was just for the sake of my example.  There are many ways to locate a particular form element in an HTML document.  The most reliable would be to give the form element an `id` attribute in the HTML, so you can use `document.getElementById` to access it.

Answer (score 1):

**Cast the form to JSObject**

Most HTML Java elements, including `HTMLFormElement`, can be directly cast to the JavaScript object `JSObject`. It is then trivial to validate the form.

Example:

```java
JSObject jsObject = (JSObject) form;
boolean valid = (boolean) jsObject.call("checkValidity");
```

Comment: Is this validation check, the html5 validation checks demonstrated at: [html5 form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) (specifically the `checkValidity()` method of the html5 constraint validation API)?

Comment: @jewelsea yes it is. It will take into account HTML properties, such as an `<input>` having the `required` tag or `type="number"`.